# Zip file size getting compromise while uploading zip file as octet-stream content type using rest service

Tags: java

My rest interface is:

```
@POST
@Path ("/xy/v1/xyz")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM})
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
Response import(InputStream fileInputStream, @Context HttpHeaders headers,
                @Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                @Context UriInfo info) {

    try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new
         ZipInputStream(fileInputStream))
    {
        ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
        while (zipEntry != null)
        {
            if(!zipEntry.isDirectory())
            {
                data= new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(zipInputStream));
                fileName = zipEntry.getName().substring(zipEntry.getName().lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                list.add(
                         //...
                                  );
            }
            zipInputStream.closeEntry();
            zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        LOG.error("Exceptions occured while reading",e);
    }
}
```

I'm getting zipEntry null if I'm using `APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM`
content-Type.

Is there a way to upload zipfile using above rest endpoint configuration?

Comment: How do you send your zipfile to the server (e.g.: your form posts multipart/form-data, but you expects application/octet-stream) ? Your client side code should send that data in the format your server side expects. The other problem can be the applied encoding, that your client code uses to send the data, if it is different from your server side settings, it will not work... if I were you, I would play it around from your favourite rest client and would try to find a request that can be consumed by your server side code.

Comment: Due to limitations of client application, they can not upload zip file to server as multipart/form-data encoding. that is why my server rest end point is expecting application/octet-stream.

Comment: I am seeking a way that I can process client zip file using application/octet-stream without loosing any byte of it. As per the setting view client and server in same configuration.

Comment: Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Application octet stream supplies File arguments

```
@POST
@Path("upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String upload(File f) {
    // ... The file contains the data uploaded
    return "ok";
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your prompt response. Unfortunately this is not working for me still zip file is getting corrupt.

Comment: You should check the client, maybe there are issues there. Or maybe the client is sending the file in base64 ... check the binary content of the file created ...